Weil height and Norm of elements in a number field
Let $k$ be a number field. For $\alpha\in k$ the Weil height is defined as$$H_k(\alpha)=\prod_{v\in M_k}\max\{1,|\alpha|_v\}^{d_v},$$where $M_k$ is the set of places of $k$, $d_v=[k_v:\mathbb{Q}_p]$. I'm wondering what is the relation with the usual Norm, of an integral element for instance. If one is bounded, the other is as well? I appreciate any help on this.

You cannot write $d_v=[k_v:\Bbb{Q}_p]$, because you want to include the archimedean places as well. You could write $\Bbb{Q}_v$ without too much of a problem, though.
To my knowledge, there isn't a direct connection between the norm and the (Weil) height of an algebraic integer. The first measures size, in some sense, and the second measures complexity, which are two different quantities. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "bounded", in your question. Even on $\Bbb{Q}$, both the norm and the height are unbounded functions. For example, on the integers (except $0$), $H_\Bbb{Q}$ is just the real absolute value, since $|z|_p\leq 1$ for $z\in\Bbb{Z}$, while $N_\Bbb{Q}$ is the identity function. Furthermore, in fact $N_\Bbb{Q}$ is the identity on all of $\Bbb{Q}$, but we see that $H_\Bbb{Q}(\frac{1}{n})=1$ for any $n\in\Bbb{Z}$.
It is true that both functions see the degree of the extension, in some sense, but that might be where the parallels end. If you have a more precise question as to how to compare them, feel free to write a comment.
